# How do I convert a latitude/longitude pair into a PostGIS geography type?

Tags: database, postgresql, gis, postgis

I'm trying to load a bunch of latitude/longitude pairs into a PostGIS geography type so as to be able to query by location.

In particular I have a table with float latitude and longitude columns and a `geography(Point, 4326)` column. I would like to do

```
update mytable set geography = ???
```

The documentation appears to suggest that the following should work:

```
update mytable set geography = ST_GeogFromText('POINT(' || latitude || ' ' ||
                                                           longitude || ')');
```

It doesn't. I don't know what it's interpreting this point as meaning, but it only allows the longitude to lie between -90 and 90, so it's clearly not a longitude.

So, what do I do?

Comment: email the list or go on irc.freenode.net #postgis

Comment: I am in #postgis. It's dead silent. Mailing the list is my next port of call.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

...sigh. Stupidity on my part. Apparently the correct order is longitude, latitude. I was fooled into thinking that both coordinates had the same range (-180 to 180) so thought something more subtle was going on.

Comment: longitude, latitude ordering sure introduces a lot of bugs.

Comment: This is still a horrible answer, and you should have accepted the advice of @MikeT with ST_MakePoint instead of string concatenation which introduces rounding errors.

Comment: You mean the ones made three and four years after I posted the question and long after I no longer had the problem?

Comment: @DRMacIver maybe he thought you completely paused your life and went into a cryogenic slumber until an answer came up

Comment: ```Apparently the correct order is longitude, latitude``` thank you very much for this info @DRMacIver! Where can I find this info in the PostGIS official docs? Sorry I've been searching but can't find it in their docs :( It's should be something that they emphasize on their docs, because as @kbrock said, it sure introduces bugs not knowing it, because usually we use lat/lon order :(

Comment: @Mon Most geodetical CRSs require coordinates in that order. You may check it for a particular CRS with a tool like `projinfo`.

Answer (score 14):

Here are some different ways to make geography types:

- Convert numeric `long` and `lat` columns to a `geog` geography type:

  ```
   UPDATE mytable SET geog = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat), 4326)::geography
  ```
- Convert a `geom` geometry column ([SRID=4326](http://epsg.io/4326)) to a `geog` geography type using a simple cast:

  ```
   UPDATE mytable SET geog = geom::geography
  ```
- Transform a projected `geom` geometry column to a `geog` geography type:

  ```
   UPDATE mytable SET geog = ST_Transform(geom, 4326)::geography
  ```

Note that the last two examples work on any geometry type. Also, the conversion from geometry to geography is often implicit, and these examples work without `::geography`, however explicit casts are usually a good practice for these things.

Answer (score 5):

To perform exchange between lat and lng you may use:

```
update mytable set geography = ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(' || st_x(geom) || ' ' ||  st_y(geom) || ')');
```

with or without srid.

Comment: This method will have some lossy round-off errors (i.e., `float8` → `text` → `float8`). Also, `ST_X` only works on `POINT` geometry types.