# Lat/Long spatial reference

Tags: postgresql, google-maps, postgis

I am new to PostGIS, am not getting the area of polygon right, my sample data is from Google maps, I know the area of the polygon is 11 acres, but the area returned by st_area doesn't match, 
I already referred to a few links like below, but unable to resolve the issue, Internet says google follows 4326 Spatial references, I tried a lot, can you please help, Image attached is the polygon from google maps.

I am expecting an array of such coordinates from the user, I have to calculate the area from PostGIS and give an error back to the user if the area entered is not approximated to calculated area.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169422/how-does-st-area-in-postgis-work

[How do I convert a latitude/longitude pair into a PostGIS geography type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523561/how-do-i-convert-a-latitude-longitude-pair-into-a-postgis-geography-type)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56862/what-spatial-reference-system-do-i-store-google-maps-lat-lng-in/56925

17.475197   78.389024
17.4771     78.39044
17.475657   78.391652
17.474408   78.390847
17.475197   78.389024

l_polygon_text='MULTIPOLYGON(((
    17.4771000000000001 78.3904399999999981,
    17.4751970000000014 78.3890240000000063,
    17.4756570000000018 78.3916519999999934,
    17.4751970000000014 78.3890240000000063,
    17.4744080000000004 78.3908469999999937,
    17.4771000000000001 78.3904399999999981)))';

```
st_area(ST_GeometryFromText(l_polygon_text,4326))
st_area(ST_GeometryFromText(l_polygon_text,2163));
st_area(ST_GeometryFromText(l_polygon_text,2249));
st_area(ST_GeometryFromText(l_polygon_text,3859));

ST_AREA(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText(l_polygon_text,4326),31467));
ST_Area(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText(l_polygon_text),4326),900913));
```

[polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZIjy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostGIS, coordinates must be expressed as longitude first, then latitude. Google uses the opposite.

After swapping the coordinates to the proper order, you can't directly call `st_area`, else you would get an area in "square degrees" which is meaningless. You would have to project to a suitable local coordinate system, or you can use the `geography` type which will return an area in m2.

```
select st_area(st_geogFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((78.3904399999999981 17.4771000000000001, 78.3890240000000063 17.4751970000000014,78.3916519999999934 17.4756570000000018,78.3890240000000063 17.4751970000000014,78.3908469999999937 17.4744080000000004,78.3904399999999981 17.4771000000000001)))'));
      st_area
--------------------
 26956.897848576307
```

That being said, the example you have provided is about 6.5 acres, not 11, because the polygon is not properly defined:

[image]

Comment: ```In PostGIS, coordinates must be expressed as longitude first, then latitude. Google uses the opposite``` Thank you for this @JGH. Where can I find this in official docs? Sorry I've been searching but can't seem to find it in official PostGIS docs :(

Comment: It should be something that they're emphasizing in their docs because it can introduce hair-pulling subtle bugs since people are used to lat-lon order :(